# Transactional PDO with MVC across multiple models

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I'm building a site and have multiple segments of code, across multiple models, that needs to run within a transaction so if one fails, the code will roll back.

Say I have a simple form to register a user.

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />         
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="username">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="username">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />   
        </div>
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></div>
    </form>
```

In my system when a user is created, I need to automatically place them in a role.

To insert into the User table, I use my User model. Then I need to insert the Role table which occurs in a separate model. If all work needed to be done lies within separate models, where do I create the connection to be passed across multiple models to allow the transaction to work?

```
// Start Transaction.
// Create new user based on posted variables. UserModel
// Add user to a given role. UserRoleModel -> Table contains UserId and RoleId
// Commit transaction.
```

Maybe where I am confused is, should all work to create a user be in my user model? Even if the work spans across more than just the User db table? My assumption is that each table in the database should have a model class and that model class should do only work within that table? Am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: well in my case i use the outer most layer of the table model to do transactions that involve, other tables. which framework are you using

Comment: No framework. Really trying to learn and understand the best approach. So your saying inside your UserModel, on create, you would insert into the user table and then insert into the user_role table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in my comment, the outer layer can interact with other tables:

Model

```
   1 DataBase  
     2  => UserTableDefinition  
             3  =>  UserDefaultInteraction 
                    4   => UserCustomFunctions  
                           5 =>  UserOuterLayer
```

And the User Role can be set up the same way. Now the all the models can interact with each other only using the outerlayer (5);

since you are learning, i will give yuou a detailed example so you can consider using a robust way of handling your model, and this simply make it easier.
example:

```
class UserOuterLayer extends UserCustomFunctions {

    public function createNewUser ($data) {
       // create a new user from array
        $user = new self();
        $user->setName($data['name']);
        $user->setUserName($data['username']);
        $user->setPassword($data['password']);
        $user->setRole($data['role']);

       if ($user->save()) { // when the object is saved it assign a new value for $user->id
            $role = new UserRole(); // accessing another model
            $role->setUserId($user->getId()); // returns the new id from the saved object
            $role->setRole($user->getRole());
            $role->save();
       }    
    }
}
```

Good Luck in your learning, i hope this makes sense :)

Comment: maybe it makes, but you are forgetting $ before data

Comment: @yes123 Thank you, i made the change now

Comment: One last thing, so you would have two classes for each model essentially?

Comment: on my case it is very abstract so i have 4 classes for each table model. i wrote a script to generate them so it's not a problem when i make changes, to the table. the first one have the columns definitions the second one has the all the get and set methods, the third make complexe data base queries with foreign keys and such. the last one is for stuff like i show in the examples above