# Writing a model for a user (php)

Tags: php

I have a users model that has a lot of properties such as first_name, last_name, email, address, address2...etc

I am writing a php class to manage these properties, but it seems like I am writing a lot of the same code. (Getters and setters). Should I use magic methods to manage this? It seems like an OK idea, but I don't want incorrect properties being set. Any ideas?

```
<?php
class User
{
    private $username;
    private $email
    private $first_name;
    private $last_name;
    private $address;
    private $address2;

    function __construct()
    {

    }

        function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->username
        }


        function setUsername($username)
        {
            $this->username = $username;
        }

        ...
}
?>
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531091/php-class-def-individual-accessors-mutators-or-set-with-switch) for some insights and comparisons between magic methods and individual accessors.

Comment: there are examples of models here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011711/transactional-pdo-with-mvc-across-multiple-models/6011916#6011916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are doing validation on the input, there's no point using getters/setters here in my opinion.

Make the properties `public`, and override the getters/setters for invalid properties using magic methods:

```
class User
{
    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $address;
    public $address2;

    public function __get($var) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid property $var");
    }

    public function __set($var, $value) {
        $this->__get($var);
    }

}

$user = new User;
$user->username = 'foo';  // works
$user->foo = 'bar';       // errors
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can't you use public properties?

If no and your properties does not require any logic when getting/setting, i would use `__get` and `__set`.

If you really don't want "incorrect" properties being set (why?), a option could be to use a whitelist of properties that's okay to set:

```
function __set($key, $value) {
    $whitelist = array("firstname", "lastname", ..);
    if(!in_array($key, $whitelist))
        throw new Exception("Invalid property");
}
```